# Unity Navmesh Agent blocked

Tags: unity-game-engine, path-finding, game-development, navmesh

I have a project where I am using NavMesh Agent and Obstacles as a core mechanics of the game. I have baked a NavMeshSurface to the ground so the Agents can find their way to the End point. The player is placing Obstacles in front of the Agents to block their path. I am struggling to make the Agents do damage to the Obstacles if they are fully blocked and there is no available path to the end point. ***Note: (By fully blocked I mean that they are just standing at one place and do nothing. If this happens I want the Agents to start attacking the Obstacles in order to make their own way to the End point)*** Any suggestions of how to check if there is available path are deeply appreciated! Thank you in advance

Comment: what have you tried? what specifically is the question

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to the community Svetoslav.

Doing quick search on *NavMeshAgent check if endpoint is reachable* yielded the answer right away (https://answers.unity.com/questions/1254520/how-to-check-if-agent-destination-can-be-reached.html
(answer by Arcana96))

> There's a method called CalculatePath which allows you check whether a position is reachable before you move the agent. Here's the documentation:
> https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/NavMeshAgent.CalculatePath.html

Using `CalculatePath` method returns `NavMeshPath` object. It can be used to check if endpoint is reachable (check the documentation). After getting positive results, you can set that path to `NavMeshAgent`'s `path` property.

Comment: Thank you so much I have implemented it and now it is working fine! I am calling it in Update() as I want to check for the path continuously. Now I will need to make the Agent to attack the closest Obstacle. Thank you for your help!